# Reformulate IF-statement in mathematical optimization

Tags: linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I have an optimization problem that chooses which location must be opened based on a set of possible locations. And per location we have a certain amount of available spots from which we must buy a number.

I have a constraint in the model which says that if a location is opened, the number of bought spots in this location must be an integer number which is at least 1. But if a location is not opened, you cannot buy any spots there.

It is modelled as follows:

- $P$ = the set of all possible locations to open
- $x_i$ = whether location $i$ is opened or not (0=not opened, 1=opened)
- $p_i$ = amount of places bought at location $i$

\begin{equation}
  p_i=\begin{cases}
    p_i \geq 1, \ p_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}, & \text{if $x_i = 1$}\\
    p_i = 0, & \text{if $x_i = 0$}
  \end{cases}
  \qquad \forall i \in P
\label{open+parking}
\end{equation}

How can I model this constraint such that I can use MILP or MIQCP to solve this optimization problem?

Comment: The constraint is $p_i\geq x_i, \ \ \forall \ i \in P$ with  $p_i\in \mathbb N_0, x_i\in \{0,1\}$

Comment: According to this constraint $p_i$ can be higher than 0 even if $x_i = 0$, however $p_i$ must be 0 if $x_i = 0$.

Comment: You're right. Next try: $p_i\leq p_i\cdot x_i$

Comment: This would allow $p_i$ to be 0 even though $x_i = 1$. But when $x_i = 1$, $p_i$ must be at least 1.

Comment: Arrrgh. Let me think a while.

Comment: My next idea is $p_ix_i\geq p_i\geq x_i$ If $x_i=1$ then $p_i\geq 1$. If $x_i=0$, then $p_i=0$.

Comment: Thanks! The answer below by VTand works, but I think this should indeed work too!

Comment: I think it works as well. All cases I've checked worked. It´s the most simple constraint formulation I can think off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is one possible way:

\begin{align*}
(2p_i - 1)(2x_i - 1) &\geq 0, \\
p_i &\geq 0, \\
p_i &\in \mathbb{Z}.
\end{align*}

When $x_i = 0$, then $2x_i - 1 < 0$. Hence, we must have $2p_i - 1 < 0$ to satisfy the first constraint. This is equivalent to $p_i < 1/2$. But, because the other two constraints say that $p_i \geq 0$ and $p_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, we only have one possible value for $p_i$, that is, $p_i = 0$.

Similarly, when $x_i = 1$, then $2x_i - 1 > 0$. Hence, we must have $2p_i - 1 > 0$ to satisfy the first constraint. This is equivalent to $p_i > 1/2$. Due to the last constraint, we must have $p_i \geq 1$ and $p_i \in \mathbb{Z}$.

---

**Addendum**.

If it is known that there is a constant $M_i$ such that $p_i \leq M_i$, we can model the variable without quadratic terms:
\begin{align*}
p_i + M_i(1-x_i) &> 0, \\
p_i + M_i(1-x_i) &\leq M_i, \\
p_i &\geq 0, \\
p_i &\in \mathbb{Z}.
\end{align*}

When $x_i = 0$, the second constraint gives us $p_i \leq 0$. Together with the third constraint, it forces $p_i$ to be $0$.

When $x_i = 1$, the first constraint becomes $p_i + 0 > 0$. Together with the third and fourth constraints, we have $p_i \geq 1$ and $p_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, as required.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work indeed!

Answer (score 2):

Let $M_i$ be a constant upper bound on $p_i$ and impose linear constraints
$$x_i \le p_i \le M_i x_i.$$

More generally, to enforce
\begin{align}
x_i=0 &\implies p_i=0 \\
x_i=1 &\implies p_i \in [m_i,M_i],
\end{align}
impose
$$m_ix_i \le p_i \le M_i x_i.$$